# How to execute same stored procedure multiple times in Oracle SQL Developer?

Tags: oracle, stored-procedures, oracle-sqldeveloper

I have a stored procedure and I need to call it several times with different sets of input. It looks like a script could do the job. How to generate the script? Ask Oracle SQL Developer (Version 4.2.0.17.089)! , So I bring up the following: [image: Run PL/SQL box]

(By the way, what is this window called? And can this be accessible from menu bar?)

I select the right stored procedure, specify the correct parameter and click 'Save File'. Here is the saved SQL file:

```
DECLARE
  I_MENU VARCHAR2(200);
  ERRMSG VARCHAR2(200);
  P_RETURNCUR SYS_REFCURSOR;
BEGIN
  I_MENU := '4';

  CMS_ACCESS_CONTROL.GETCMSMENUITEMINFO(
    I_MENU => I_MENU,
    ERRMSG => ERRMSG,
    P_RETURNCUR => P_RETURNCUR
  );
  /* Legacy output: 
DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('ERRMSG = ' || ERRMSG);
*/ 
  :ERRMSG := ERRMSG;
  /* Legacy output: 
DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('P_RETURNCUR = ' || P_RETURNCUR);
*/ 
  :P_RETURNCUR := P_RETURNCUR; --<-- Cursor
--rollback; 
END;
```

I want to copy and paste the lines between `BEGIN` and `END` several times. Each time specify its set of input parameters (different I_MENU). But before doing so, I try to execute the file in SQL Developer. I have not made any modification but get this error:

```
Error report -
ORA-06550: Line 20, column 22
PLS-00382: expression is of wrong type
ORA-06550: Line 20, column 4
PL/SQL: Statement ignored
06550. 00000 -  "line %s, column %s:\n%s"
*Cause:    Usually a PL/SQL compilation error.
*Action:
```

Questions: 1) Why do I get this error? 2) How to call same stored procedure multiple times with different set of parameters? I want a script to do so as I have to pass the script to another person to execute.

Here is the stored procedure (there is absolutely no `/` after `end getCMSMenuItemInfo`)

```
Procedure getCMSMenuItemInfo(
    i_menu                       in varchar2,     
    ERRMSG                       out varchar2,
    P_RETURNCUR                  out SYS_REFCURSOR)
as
begin
    open P_RETURNCUR for

    SELECT menu_item, menu_url
    FROM someMenu
    WHERE menuID = i_menu;

end getCMSMenuItemInfo;
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Using `:ERRMSG` and `:P_RETURNCUR` leading to your error. You're trying to assign value to variable with syntax `:variable_a := variable_b` which is not allowed in query worksheet. Uncomment legacy output `DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE();` to testing your procedure.
2. Looking for another answer.

Answer (score 0):

I am giving this solution based on a assumption that you have certain criteria of selecting different menuid's which you will be passing to your procedure "CMS_ACCESS_CONTROL.GETCMSMENUITEMINFO". I will tell you my approach both theoretically and  will provide you the code as well.

**Solution:**

***Theoretical Approach:***

You can store your menuid's in a different table and loop over that table while calling the procedure. Now you have to decide how many and what different values you want to pass to your procedure.

***Sampe Code:***

```
create table store_id
(
id number
);  

insert into store_id select distinct menuID from someMenu;
```

You can insert the different menuid's based on your business requirement.

```
DECLARE
  I_MENU VARCHAR2(200);
  ERRMSG VARCHAR2(200);
  P_RETURNCUR SYS_REFCURSOR;
BEGIN
for i in (select id from store_id ) loop

  I_MENU := i.id;

  GETCMSMENUITEMINFO(
    I_MENU => I_MENU,
    ERRMSG => ERRMSG,
    P_RETURNCUR => P_RETURNCUR
  );


  /* Legacy output: 
DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('ERRMSG = ' || ERRMSG);
*/ 
  ERRMSG := ERRMSG;
  /* Legacy output: 
DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('P_RETURNCUR = ' || P_RETURNCUR);
*/ 
  P_RETURNCUR := P_RETURNCUR; --<-- Cursor
--rollback; 
end loop;
END;
```

I hope this helps.